# android studio webview camera permission on kitkat

Tags: java, android-studio

I made a webview of my website that have video record function. It works on marshmallow and up but not in kitkat and lollipop. Is there a way to make it work on kitkat and lollipop? here is my codes:

> XML page

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.MICROPHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />





    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

> Java page

```
public WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("https://.online"); //web url

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); //to prevent openning new window
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    });


}
```

I tried searching but the only thing I found is for marshmallow and up version

Comment: then what is your problem ? can I see the error output or stacktrace etc ?

Comment: The problem is that the record video does not work on my kitkat device but works in marshmallow and up...I'm trying to know how to enable camera permission in kitkat version @AnNguyen